# How can I convert this command line code to run in PowerShell ISE 2.0?

Tags: powershell, command-line, automation, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

So I'm using this console command to open a file using a specific application and then passing in a parameter (spacing used to make it more legible)

```
start C:\"Documents and Settings"\User\"My Documents"\Application_folder\Application.exe 

"C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\file_folder\file.type" 

"Parameter1"
```

Now I want to be able to call this same command but in PowerShell ISE. I've tried a few variations but none work. I'm not all that familiar with PowerShell, so would anyone be able to school me on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
& 'C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\Application_folder\Application.exe' "C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\file_folder\file.type" "Parameter1"
```